# Getting latest logs from azure diagnostics

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-cloud-services

After enabling diagnostics on a cloud service hosted on Microsoft Azure, the WadWindowsEventLogs table is showing the log data only after about 6 hours from the event. Is there any way to retrieve the latest event logs? Its my company project, so i won't be able to post a code piece. Hope that you will understand that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See if this blog post helps: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks.

Comment: You may also check out custom solutions for easy log access and management. See [this](http://trypour.com) as an example.