# GenerateFilterConditionOnDate not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-table-storage

I have created a cloud service that takes data from WadWindowsEventLogs table of Azure Storage and returns a csv file from it. But when i generate a filter condition on table query for date, it returns an empty csv file with no rows at all.
My function to return a string is

```
public string retrieveWADWindowsEventLogsTable()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("DefaultConnectionString"));

        CsvExport myExport = new CsvExport();
        //Creating a table client
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        //getting reference to the desired table
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("WADWindowsEventLogsTable");

        TableQuery<WADWindowsEventLogsTableEntity> query = new TableQuery<WADWindowsEventLogsTableEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("TimeStamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, new DateTime(2016,02,01)));

        //For each row in table, creating the corresponding entry in CSV file
        foreach (WADWindowsEventLogsTableEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
        {
            //some code 

        }

        var exp = myExport.Export();
        return exp;
    }
```

After that i have another function to convert this string into csv that i don't think is needed in context of this question. 
Then My entity class is

```
public class WADWindowsEventLogsTableEntity : TableEntity
{
    public WADWindowsEventLogsTableEntity()
    {

    }
    //public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    //public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public string Channel { get; set; }
    public string DeploymentId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Int32 EventId { get; set; }
    public Int64 EventTickCount { get; set; }
    public Int32 Level { get; set; }
    public Int32 Opcode { get; set; }
    public Int32 Pid { get; set; }
    public DateTime PreciseTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string ProviderGuid { get; set; }
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public string RawXml { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string RoleInstance { get; set; }
    public string RowIndex { get; set; }
    public DateTime TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
    public Int32 Task { get; set; }
    public Int32 Tid { get; set; }

}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why are you querying on `Timestamp` property? As mentioned in my comment in your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316006/getting-latest-logs-from-azure-diagnostics), please look at my blog post. Use `PartitionKey` for querying.

Comment: @GauravMantri the requirement is such that i have to retrieve the logs after a particular time. And now your website is blocked by company's proxy server, so i can't open it up anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my [`blog`](http://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/), the `PartitionKey` value in these tables actually represent the time when the log was created. It is essentially `Ticks` property of the `DateTime` value appended with a `0`. What you would need to do is take the Date/Time you're interested in, calculate its `Ticks` value and prepend a `0` to it. Then use that value in your query. Something like below:

```
        var dateTime = new DateTime(2016, 02, 01, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var partitionKeyValue = "0" + dateTime.Ticks;
        TableQuery<WADWindowsEventLogsTableEntity> query = new TableQuery<WADWindowsEventLogsTableEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, partitionKeyValue));
```

The  reason your code is not working is because you're querying your table on `Timestamp` attribute which is not indexed by Table Service. Hence your query is performing full table scan. If your table is big, then it won't return any result but a continuation token. You can use this continuation token to fetch next set of entries.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Worked perfectly.